# VB6 integration to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, vb6

I’ve been looking around for a tool that will integrate VB6 and TFS 2010.  I came across [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=87E1FFBD-A484-4C3A-8776-D560AB1E6198&displaylang=en), but it doesn’t seem to work for VS2008/10.  Does anyone know if this has been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I think this might be what you're looking for:

[Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6)